Does a subfloor over a cement slab and under carpet help insulate room from cold?
Making sunroom a full-season room. will a subfloor over the cement slab and under indoor-outdoor carpet help with heating in the winter?
Also what are the pro's & cons of using carpet padding in the sun-room (occasionally will get rain from windows)

Will help some.  Does depend on how cold is cold. Florida cold or Canadian cold?  Do not use carpet/wood type flooring if there is moisture problems/it can get wet.  Insulation/in floor heating system might help more, depending how cold it gets.
